# Pandoc Markdown to HTML blockquote style

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc, thunderbird

I'm trying to find a good solution to writing my emails in Markdown, and styling them for general consumption, in Thunderbird.

My previous solution, the add-on [Markdown-here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here) is not maintained, and no longer works with the latest Thunderbird versions.

One approach I've tried to some success is using pandoc, and inserting the contents of the HTML file via `Insert->HTML`.

E.g.:

**email.md**

```
Hi there, *this* is a **test** email written in `markdown`
```

**pandoc command**

```
pandoc email.md -t html -o email.html
```

**email.html**

```
<p>Hi there, <em>this</em> is a <strong>test</strong> email written in <code>markdown</code></p>
```

However, the formatting is not always what I want.  For example, in Markdown-here, it used to resembles the rendering of StackOverflow for blockquotes

> Blockquotes look like this

However, in my pandoc->Thunderbird workflow, HTML elements like this:

```
<blockquote>
<p>Blockquotes looks like this</p>
</blockquote>
```

are rendered as indented text like:

Blockquotes look like this

Which makes my emails less easy to follow.

I've read about pandoc having a `--css` flag, where you can define a CSS sheet to use, e.g. `s --css=styling.css`.  However, nothing I've tried seems to work.

Does anyone know how to embed changes to the blockquote styles of generated HTML in pandoc to more closely follow the rendered markdown styles of StackOverflow and GitHub?

Comment: please consider accepting this answer if you found it useful

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful.  In the following weeks one of the Thunderbird devs revived the Markdown-here extension to cover my use-case, <https://gitlab.com/jfx2006/markdown-here-revival>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) you can link to a CSS file using the `-c` flag , and we can look at SO's blockquote style, which is:

```css
   blockquote p::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #c8ccd0;
    }
blockquote{
    color:#535a60;
    padding:.8em .8em .8em 1em;
    position: relative;
}
```

So, running the following with that style should give you what you want.

`pandoc -s -c <StyleFile>.css <Content>.md -o <Output>.html`